# Matlab: linprog violates constraints

Tags: matlab, optional-parameters, linear-programming

I have a linear programming optimization, with an equality constraint. (min f'*x such that Aeq *x = beq, x >= lb)

```
linprog(f,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,[],x0,options)
```

When i get the result, it should be valid that Aeq*x=beq, but it is violated in the output by:

```
norm(Aeq*x-beq)=4.7919e-05
```

the output variable gives
output.constrviolation=3.2781e-05

I use the 'interior-point' algorithm, it seams there is no option to lower the tolerance to this violation ([in the dual-simplex it can be done with TolCon](http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html))?

Comment: The documentation you linked to says that an explicit option for controlling primal tolerance exists only for the dual simplex algorithm. You could formulate the dual of your original problem and tune the tolerance of the dual feasibility. This will work because the dual of the dual is the primal itself. It sounds ugly, but there seems to be no other way.. You could also add a large term in the objective (bigM*abs(Aeq*x-beq), which can be linearized), but this is even uglier, and can lead to numerical issues..

Comment: It is even worse, because i have Matlab R2013a, and there is not even the dual simplex algorithm available.

Comment: In such a case you are better off if you hook up an external solver. It seem that lpSolve has a [MatLab API](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/MATLAB.htm) with instructions, and a [command](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/set_epsb.htm) by which you can set the primal feasibility tolerance.